# How to switch on PixMob-like led bracelet?

Tags: radio, remote-control

I've a led bracelet, which was switched on and controlled by concert organizer (the bracelet called '[fanband](http://fanband.org/)' and according to the official site controlled either by special remote or by sound). I thought that this is [PixMob bracelet](http://yeokhengmeng.com/2016/08/partial-reverse-engineering-the-ndp-2016-led-wristband/), but it is not. See attached image to see what is inside.
I searched for CY-RF310, but found nothing.

The question I have is how to switch it on and control then?

[image]

Comment: How is this a repair question? Someone is abusing the close votes.

Comment: The number you need to concentrate on is the black chip.  Without it, is a wild guessing game.  If there is no obvious power source, I guess it could be using RF energy to provide the power (if it does not need too much).  That could be the way to turn it on. Good luck.

Comment: @Guill, this is what I wanted to do initially, but there is no any text on the black chips.